# Internal Server Error 500 upon activation of a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, internal-server-error

My WP installation generates a `Internal Error 500` every time I activate the `BuddyPress` plugin.

This is the actual error:

> [Sat Mar 28 19:12:28.102868 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 10447] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.1.1:55431] FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/clients/client1/web4/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-*-80-site.eu" aborted: read failed, referer: http://site.eu/wp-admin/update.php?action=install-plugin&plugin=buddypress&_wpnonce=54e15a2310
>
> [Sat Mar 28 19:12:28.103055 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 10447] [client 192.168.1.1:55431] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/clients/client1/web4/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-*-80-site.eu", referer: http://site.eu/wp-admin/update.php?action=install-plugin&plugin=buddypress&_wpnonce=54e15a2310`

How should I solve that?

P.S. The strange thing is that before, when the server was running Ubuntu 12, I had no troubles activating and using BuddyPress. Then something possessed me and I decided to upgrade the OS to 14.04 and as a result the site became inaccessible. Finally, I figured that it was BuddyPress that was causing the issue, removed it from the plugins folder and the site went back to working. Now every time I try to re-add BP, I get the error above.

Comment: hey there. I tried to improve your question a bit by removing some noise and formatting the error in a quote instead of code to prevent having to scroll horizontally. If you have any more details please edit them in your question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/unable-to-install-wordpress-plugin.67201/), installing this plugins cause the fcgi process for PHP to hit its memory limit or execution time limit, preventing it to properly finish.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. Could you help me find a way around this? I've added some information in the OP.